# (ASP) MS Access -> MySQL: Error in Select, where [..] strings

Tags: mysql, ms-access, select, asp-classic, where-clause

I am using a portal system on my website and modified the ASP code heavily.
Since the website is growing, I want to migrate from MS Acces to MySQL.

Now, I think the portal I'm using (and some code I inputted) aren't MySQL compatable, because when I switch to the MySQL database, I get the following error.

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'
>
> [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.1.55-community]You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near '[EzModuleID],
>   [ModName] From EzCore_Plugin Where IsModActive='1'' at line 1
>
> [website]\WWWROOT\BOXX\INCLUDES../../includes/include.asp, line 3736

The SQL string regarding this line is the following:

```sql
Select [EzModuleID], [ModName] From EzCore_Plugin Where [IsModActive] = 1;
```

Im new to MySQL and I can't find why this is giving an error.
I've tried the quote's around 1, removing [], removing the space..
I think that when I figure out why this is causing an error, I can continue modifying the rest to make the website work on mysql.

Comment: Such a simple solution.. Thanks. :)

Im trying to change all that code to fit mysql. An error i dont understand is this next one:

>ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1'
>
>Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.
>
>/includes/custom-header.asp, line 399

This error didnt occour with acces, why cant MySQL find it?

> if rs("pollvoted.memberid") = rs("groupmembers.memberid") then

Comment: I'd try something like `Select pollvoted.memberid as memberid1, groupmembers.memberid as memberid2, ...`, and then use `rs("memberid1")` etc. Either that or run the query via a command line or with an admin tool and see what names MySQL assigns to the columns in the output

Comment: Out of interest why have you chosen MySQL over SQL Server Express edition.  I'm not trying to recommend one database over another, but if you've been using Access then migrating to SQL Server would probably involve less work

Comment: MySQL is free at my webhost.. SQL requires an additional fee..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the square brackets

(I might as well post this as the answer rather than a comment)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL column and table names can be escaped with the backtick character `` ` `` or if the ANSI SQL mode is enabled with double quotes `"`.

Your WHERE clause (according to the error message) is `Where IsModActive='1'`. This works if `IsModActive` is a text column. If it is numeric, drop the single quotes. If `IsModActive` is a Boolean, change the clause to `Where IsModActive IS true`.

See: [is operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is)